# Does Vega Support Text in HTML or Markdown Format?

Tags: vega

I want to display text containing links using Vega and would also want the ability to style those texts (headlines, emphasis, italics, dropdown).

Can I style text in Vega using the HTML or Markdown format?

If not, are there comparable alternatives supported by the Vega library?

This is a [link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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-BwysFTsFTRBFB+4Pxo3a7lJW9C8scPqI4OAGo4fBRukQPj4XInYMAWQAMhVSrkrw9lFAaGBBy6bPcYO0BwAxU8hEEN4KgAdSrGAIzoXIo1zY0YMEc0BAWcw13cEoyhwBcFTeSsdgPI9ckUBUbAeN5WjVNwPHhHk3k9PlEBZEksF1ei7UQIVmJAGMcAAITsNs2KDAc1XVMIgA) to my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no markdown but you can style the text using fontStyle for italics or fontWeight for bold. You can also assign a href to the whole mark but not individual text elements within it. Details are all here: https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/marks/text/

Comment: Thank you David, I thought as much after reading the documentation but just wanted to ask to verify.